# SfTabView - Setting TabWidthMode to SizeToContent generates causes gap before the first header

Tags: xaml, maui, syncfusion, tabview

Using this code:

```
<tabView:SfTabView x:Name="tabView"
                   TabWidthMode="SizeToContent">
    <tabView:SfTabView.Items>
        <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Item" />
        <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Item" />
        <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Item" />
        <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Item" />
    </tabView:SfTabView.Items>
</tabView:SfTabView>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I could not figure out, how I can remove the gab (margin and padding do not effect it).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue and raised a ticket with Syncfusion. In response they have raised a feature request for configurable padding on TabViewHeader here https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/40702/provide-padding-support-for-tabheader-in-sftabview?_gl=1*1q0gkf3*_ga*NjQ4MTYwNTgwLjE2OTQwMDk2OTA.*_ga_41J4HFMX1J*MTcwODI1NDU1OC44OS4xLjE3MDgyNTQ1NjYuMC4wLjA. please upvote the feature request to get them to prioritise it. Thanks!